# Mathematical approach that can be use to solve this problem.

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

I'm having a problem to find the best mathematical approach to solve below problem.

The problem statement::

"Jane staying at 13th floor, Jane goes to 15 floors downstairs for taking a gift that she left in her car. Then she goes upstairs to Marry house. Bob staying at 10th floor, he goes 6 floors upstairs to call his cousin and then goes downstairs to Marry house.

If the distance covered by Jane and Bob are same, what is the floor of Marry house?"

Now, what is the best mathematical approach that we can use to solve above problem instead of using mind logic? Could it be using matrix or classic algebra can solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like arithmetic to me, but I don't understand how Jane can go 15 floors downstairs if she's staying at the 13th floor. She goes to floor negative two? And what does it mean for the movements of Jane and Bob to be the same? If they start at different places, and have the same movements, how can they wind up at the same place?

Comment: @Gerry: There's a parking garage in basement levels -1 to -5.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Azizul?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be Mary's floor. Jane goes 15 floors down, then $x+1$ floors up (we assume there's no floor zero), total, $x+16$. Bob goes 6 floors up, then $16-x$ down, total, $22-x$. As they cover the same distance, $x+16=22-x$. I'm sure you can take it from there.